# Excel VBA save to master worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a VBA code which attaches daily trading activity into the body of an email, attaches the workbook as an email and sends it out to the relevant groups. I've tried to incorporate VBA code which will also automatically store data from separate worksheets on to one master worksheet, however I cannot seem to get this to work.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1) = Date
    Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
    'You can also use a sheet name
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "some@mail.addr"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Today's Trades" & Date
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send                                    'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Sub AppendDataAfterLastColumn()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Fill in the column(s) that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A:G")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Columns.Count > DestSh.Columns.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough columns in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats and Column width
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(1, Last + 1)
                .PasteSpecial 8    ' Column width
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Apologies for the length of the code, however any suggestions on how I should structure the VBA in order to get it to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may get better responses if you are more specific in your question. What *exactly* is not working? Which part of the code are you referring to? What happens instead? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for helping with the edit, did not realise I had left my email in.

Comment: You did not define "Last"; you probably need something like...  `Last = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: @GMalc Where would I include this in my VBA? I do apologise if its a bit of an obvious question as I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: I would place it below this line; `DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"`, and ensure that it references the correct worksheet, e.g. `Last = DestSh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Also, since you know the number of columns that you are going to copy, i would Remove "CopyRng.Columns.Count", and change it to `If Last + 7 > DestSh.Columns.Count Then`